# A blockA piece of internal use another blockB block will be a circular reference, how a weak reference is quoted blockA block blockB piece?

Tags: objective-c

A blockA piece of internal use another blockB block will be a circular reference, how a weak reference is quoted blockA block blockB piece?

```
- (UIView *)creatSuviewWithPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder reminder:(NSString *)reminder clickBlock:( void(^)())clickBlock {

    UIView *containView = [UIView new];
    [self.view addSubview:containView];
    PlaceholderTextView *textView = [PlaceholderTextView new];
    [containView addSubview:textView];
    if (clickBlock) {
        textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [containView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithActionBlock:^(id  _Nonnull sender) {//blockA
           clickBlock();//blockB
        }]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something there is no obvious reference cycle in *the code you show*, why do you believe there is?

Your inline block, labelled `blockA` in the comments, references `clickBlock`; but `clickBlock` does not reference `blockA` or `containView` so no cycle is created.

Does `clickBlock` itself reference `self.view`, or something else which creates the cycle? If so edit your question to show this and someone will undoubtedly help.

Comment: clickBlock reference containView，I hope weak reference clickBlock

Comment: `clickBlock` is a parameter to your method and `containView` is first created in the method - so `clickBlock` cannot *directly* reference `containView`. It could do so via `self.view`. You need to edit the question and add code such as that which sets up `self.view`, calls `creatSuviewWithPlaceholder`, creates the block passed as `clickBlock` etc. That will enable people to see the cycle you are concerned about and hopefully help you with a solution.